# what is the view that we use in any Android homescreen?

Tags: android, view, swipe, homescreen

i am developing an app which uses gestures,i have got the code from internet for gestures,studied it,that's not a problem.Its difficult to put in words so i m giving an e.g.

you all would have noticed how the home screen of the android devices work.when a user swipes left or right the background slides along with it and our view changes...i mean another activity is not launched,just the view slides...i just wanna know what kind of view is that??and can we implement it in our apps??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard **Launcher2** workspace is composed of a *Workspace* which extends    *SmoothPagedView* which extends  *PagedView* which extends *ViewGroup* which contains **5** workspace screen which are *CellLayout* extending *ViewGroup*.
No ViewPager as somebody mentioned.
See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/+/master

Comment: thanx . Can you please give me the link of a tutorial???the link u gave is all code and no proper documentation